# convert function into member function?

Tags: c++

I'm new here and I'm looking for help with a program written in c++.

I want to convert following functions that are not in a class nor in main() of my program

```
void PrintInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);
vector<Item*> AddItemToInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);
vector<Item*> UpdateItemQtyInInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);
vector<Item*> RemoveItemFromInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);
```

into public function members of a class Inventory that have no parameters and return nothing.

I've been working on that for 4 days now and just can't figure out how I'm supposed to change these functions to be void and have no parameter without destroying the whole program...

If I go exactly by what the instruction say which is to make a void/no parameters out of the four functions, I would get something like:

```
class Inventory
{
public:
    void PrintInventory() {}
    void AddItemToInventory() {}
    void UpdateItemQtyInInventory() {}
    void RemoveItemFromInventory() {}

private:
    vector<Item*> inventory;
};
```

Please give me a hint. I feel like the solution must be simple but I've been completely stuck for days.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I'm still getting a bunch of errors and think I need to say a bit more about my code:
I have a base class Item and two derived classes Produce and Book. Then I have four function calls:

```
// Print all items in the inventory
void PrintInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);

// Dialogue to create a new item, then add that item to the inventory
vector<Item*> AddItemToInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);

// Dialogue to update the quantity of an item, then update that item in the inventory
vector<Item*> UpdateItemQtyInInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);

// Dialogue to remove a specific item, then remove that specific item from the inventory
vector<Item*> RemoveItemFromInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);
```

Next comes the main and my class Inventory that now has four converted functions with no return and no parameters that were not originally inside the class Inventory and had parameters/return before.

Here is the whole code, I think it's better to understand this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Item {
public:
    void SetName(string nm)
    {
        name = nm;
    };
    void SetQuantity(int qnty)
    {
        quantity = qnty;
    };
    void SetPrice(int prcInDllrs) //step1
    {
        priceInDollars = prcInDllrs; //step1
    };
    virtual void Print()
    {
        cout << name << " " << quantity << endl;
    };
    virtual ~Item()
    {
        return;
    };
protected:
    string name;
    int    quantity;
    int    priceInDollars; //step1
};

class Produce : public Item { // Derived from Item class
public:
    void SetExpiration(string expir)
    {
        expiration = expir;
    };
    void Print()
    {
        cout << name << " x" << quantity
            << " for $" << priceInDollars //step1
            << " (Expires: " << expiration << ")"
            << endl;
    };
private:
    string expiration;
};

//step 2 add derived class Book 
class Book : public Item { // Derived from Item class
public:
    void SetAuthor(string authr) //create author function with parameter
    {
        author = authr;
    };
    void Print()
    {
        cout << name << " x" << quantity
            << " for $" << priceInDollars //step1
            << " (Author: " << author << ")"
            << endl;
    };
private:
    string author;
};

// Print all items in the inventory
void PrintInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);

// Dialogue to create a new item, then add that item to the inventory
vector<Item*> AddItemToInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);

// Dialogue to update the quantity of an item, then update that item in the inventory
vector<Item*> UpdateItemQtyInInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);

// Dialogue to remove a specific item, then remove that specific item from the inventory
vector<Item*> RemoveItemFromInventory(vector<Item*> inventory);

int main() {
    vector<Item*> inventory;
    string usrInptOptn = "default";

    while (true) {
        // Get user choice
        cout << "\nEnter (p)rint, (a)dd, (u)pdate, (r)emove, or (q)uit: ";
        getline(cin, usrInptOptn);

        // Process user choice
        if (usrInptOptn.size() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'p') {
            PrintInventory(inventory);
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'a') {
            inventory = AddItemToInventory(inventory);
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'u') {
            inventory = UpdateItemQtyInInventory(inventory);
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'r') {
            inventory = RemoveItemFromInventory(inventory);
        }
        else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'q') {
            cout << "\nGood bye." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

class Inventory {
public:

    void PrintInventory() {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to print." << endl;
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i<inventory.size(); ++i) {
                cout << i << " - ";
                inventory.at(i)->Print();
            }
        };
    }
    void AddItemToInventory() {


        Produce* prdc;
        Book* book; //create new pointer object of class book
        string usrInptName = "";
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";
        istringstream inSS;
        int usrInptQnty = 0;
        string usrInptExpr = "";
        int usrInptPrc = 0; //step1
        string usrInptAuthr = ""; //declare variable
        string usrInptBookName = "";
        int usrInptQntyBook = 0;
        string usrInptQntyBookStr = "";
        string usrInptChoice = " ";


        //loop user choice and ask again if choice is not valid
        do {
            cout << "Enter choice of adding (b)ook or (p)roduce: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptChoice);
            if (usrInptChoice != "b" && usrInptChoice != "p") {
                cout << "Invalid Choice" << endl;
            }
        } while (usrInptChoice != "b" && usrInptChoice != "p");

        //only ask for inventory type accoring to user input p or b
        if (usrInptChoice == "p") {

            cout << "Enter name of new produce: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptName);

            cout << "Enter quantity: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptQntyStr);
            inSS.str(usrInptQntyStr);
            inSS >> usrInptQnty;
            inSS.clear();

            cout << "Enter expiration date: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptExpr);

            cout << "Enter the price per item : $"; //step1
            cin >> usrInptPrc; //step1

            prdc = new Produce;
            prdc->SetName(usrInptName);
            prdc->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
            prdc->SetExpiration(usrInptExpr);
            prdc->SetPrice(usrInptPrc);

            inventory.push_back(prdc);
        }

        if (usrInptChoice == "b") {
            cout << "Enter name of new book: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptBookName);

            cout << "Enter quantity: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptQntyBookStr);
            inSS.str(usrInptQntyBookStr);
            inSS >> usrInptQntyBook;
            inSS.clear();

            cout << "Enter author: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptAuthr);

            cout << "Enter the price per item : $"; //step1
            cin >> usrInptPrc; //step1

            book = new Book;
            book->SetName(usrInptBookName);
            book->SetQuantity(usrInptQntyBook);
            book->SetAuthor(usrInptAuthr);
            book->SetPrice(usrInptPrc);

            inventory.push_back(book);
        };
    }

    void UpdateItemQtyInInventory() {
        string usrIndexChoiceStr = "";
        unsigned int usrIndexChoice = 0;
        istringstream inSS;
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";
        int usrInptQnty = 0;

        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to update." << endl;
        }
        else {
            PrintInventory();

            do {
                cout << "Update which item #: ";
                getline(cin, usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS.str(usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS >> usrIndexChoice;
                inSS.clear();
            } while (!(usrIndexChoice < inventory.size()));

            cout << "Enter new quantity: ";
            getline(cin, usrInptQntyStr);
            inSS.str(usrInptQntyStr);
            inSS >> usrInptQnty;
            inSS.clear();

            inventory.at(usrIndexChoice)->SetQuantity(usrInptQnty);
        };
    }

    void RemoveItemFromInventory() {
        istringstream inSS;
        string usrIndexChoiceStr = "";
        unsigned int usrIndexChoice = 0;
        string usrInptQntyStr = "";

        if (inventory.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No items to remove." << endl;
        }
        else {
            PrintInventory();

            do {
                cout << "Remove which item #: ";
                getline(cin, usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS.str(usrIndexChoiceStr);
                inSS >> usrIndexChoice;
                inSS.clear();
            } while (!(usrIndexChoice < inventory.size()));

            inventory.erase(inventory.begin() + usrIndexChoice);
        };
    }

    private:
        vector<Item*> inventory;
};
```

I don't get any compilation errors in Visual Studio but when I try to build, there are 5 errors. Compiling the program in Geany gives me no errors either but when I build, it says:

```
    undefined reference to `PrintInventory(std::vector<Item*, std::allocator<Item*> >)'
   undefined reference to `AddItemToInventory(std::vector<Item*, std::allocator<Item*> >)'
   undefined reference to `UpdateItemQtyInInventory(std::vector<Item*, std::allocator<Item*> >)'
     undefined reference to `RemoveItemFromInventory(std::vector<Item*, std::allocator<Item*> >)'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Compilation failed.
```

I feel like I'm missing some basic, simple thing but I just can't figure it out. The instruction is confusing to me when it says I have to convert the functions PrintInventory, AddItemToInventory, UpdateItemQtyInInventory,
and RemoveItemFromInventory into void/no parameters but which functions does it refer to? The four definition lines? The actual functions? Both? And what about the main and the other classes? Wouldn't I need to change things there as well?

Comment: What do you surmise the member variable `inventory` gives you?

Comment: If I understand your question, my answer would be that the member variable inventory gives me a vector of pointers needed in my main and other classes. For example:
int main() {
 vector<Item*> inventory;
 string usrInptOptn = "default";

 while (true) {
  // Get user choice
  cout << "\nEnter (p)rint, (a)dd, (u)pdate, (r)emove, or (q)uit: ";
  getline(cin, usrInptOptn);

  // Process user choice
  if (usrInptOptn.size() == 0) {
   continue;
  }
  else if (usrInptOptn.at(0) == 'p') {
   PrintInventory(inventory);}
  and so on

Comment: It gives you a vector owned by your `Inventory` object. The member functions of that `Inventory` object can access that vector. Consequently, they need no vector passed to them. And please don't paste code walls in comments.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited my post to show the full code but still get errors. It seems like after making adjustments, the functions really can access the vector and don't need any parameters passed or return statements but now I get errors in the other classes. I thought it is obvious that this is going to happen when I change the code like I did...

Comment: Those other non-member functions don't need to be declared anymore. And your `main()` should look something [**like this**](http://pastebin.com/vE5RLYn2).

Comment: I've really tried that before but then I thought I'm doing things wrong since I get a lot of errors saying that Inventory has not been identified in line Inventory inv; and all the other functions that I call such us using inv.PrintInventory give me undeclared identifier.

Comment: The class definition of `Inventory` has to come *before* `main()` somehow. Move it above `main()` and it should work.

Comment: OMG!!! I can't believe it!! You are correct! This was the problem!! grrrrrrrr... I had these issues before but didn't think of it this time! Can't believe I spent more than 4 days trying to solve this. Why exactly can't c++ do this stuff automatically? I mean I know a program starts reading lines from the beginning to the end but I can't see why it doesn't automatically pick out important things like that and reads them first... I guess that's also why constructors are useful?

Answer (score 0):

Basic testing:

Note, there are no pointers in here

```
void test()
{
    class T_item
    {
    public:
        string name;
        int    quantity;
        int    priceInDollars;
    };

    vector<T_item> inventory;

    T_item temp;

    //add item:
    temp.name = "name1";
    temp.quantity = 1;
    temp.priceInDollars = 1;
    inventory.push_back(temp);

    temp.name = "name2";
    temp.quantity = 2;
    temp.priceInDollars = 2;
    inventory.push_back(temp);

    cout << "print:\n";
    for each(T_item item in inventory)
    {
        cout << item.name << endl;
        cout << item.quantity << endl;
        cout << item.priceInDollars << endl << endl;
    }

    //modify item at index 1:
    inventory[1].name = "modified";

    //delete item at index 0:
    inventory.erase(inventory.begin() + 0);

    cout << "print again:\n";
    for each(T_item item in inventory)
    {
        cout << item.name << endl;
        cout << item.quantity << endl;
        cout << item.priceInDollars << endl << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As you can see in my edited post, class Item only has a virtual destructor. I adjusted the code but it seems like I'm missing something because I still get errors when building, although I have no compilation mistakes... I think I need to adjust more than just the Inventory class when I change the functions into void with no parameters. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand your code. I think you should try with something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code conversion is correct. Since 'Inventory vector' is a a member variable it can be accessed by all the other member function and can also be manipulated. This removes the requirement for passing vector as argument.
Now for returning the vector I would suggest adding a new "GetInventory()" method which returns the vector or take a reference to pass the vector.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited my post and I get errors. Do you know why? It's so frustrating I've been sitting here for days trying all kind of things with no success but I'm convinced the problem is simple...

Comment: I believe you have problems because of not defining the functions which you have declared. First the code which you have written is not a good C++ code. Every thing should be wrapped in a class and then used through objects. Wrap your functions in a class. Also you need to define your functions. If you don't want them in a class then make them global under a header file and include it in your program. currently your program is itself wrong. Do a self review I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  WhozCraig, my problem has been solved:

"The class definition of Inventory has to come before main() somehow. Move it above main() and it should work."